# Perform a task in spring after application context start so that task failure wont affect application start

Tags: spring

I have a task that i need to perform at the time of application startup in spring (context start).
There were cases when that task can fail (data may not be ready) and its causing the application start to fail. My question is :

1. What is the best way to do it so that task success/failure wont affect the start?                                                                         Note : The case is that we have to run the task at-least once after start of context?

Comment: If you need to run the task, then why is it a bad thing if the program halts if it fails?

Comment: We have to run it for sure but not mandatory to run with context start it can run later too. The bad part is its crashing the startup on failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a spring component listening for the spring context started event. Something like this:

```
@Component
public class SpringCtxListener {

    @EventListener
    public void checkUser(ContextRefreshedEvent cre) throws Exception
    {
        //This method is called when Spring context has started and here you can execute your task
    }
}
```

Angelo

Comment: Thanks for the response this is good i think. As of now i using something like where i am scheduling it after some delay, to be run once in a day every day and its working fine.                   
    `@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
     public void doSomething() {
     // something that should execute on weekdays only
    }`

Answer (score 1):

What @Angelo provided can work too.
I am going with following. Which will be running this task after context refresh/start is done.
 `@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI") 
  public void doSomething() 
 { // something that should execute on weekdays only }`

NOTE: The requirement changed a bit where i have to do this task everyday at-least once hence using @Scheduled

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but might do the trick:

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void doTask() {
       int i = 0;
        try {
            doTheTask();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            if (i == 10) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            Thread.sleep(200);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will run the task 10 times before giving up, waiting 200ms between each attempt. Note that if the same thread that is being put to sleep here is used to ready the data, it won't help, you would have to put the running of the task in a separate thread.

Another possibility is using `Spring`'s `@Scheduled`:

First, you need to enable scheduling. This is done either by the `@EnableScheduling` in your java config, or with some xml:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="printMessage" fixed-delay="5000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler"/>
```

Next, annotate the method with `@Scheduled`:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay= 600000) //ms, =10 minutes
public void doTask() {
   doTheTask();
}
```

Note that there is still no guarantee for the task actually succeeding. You could combine it `fixedDelay` to run it multiple times, but note that any exception thrown out of the method will halt the series of execution. For a more guaranteed run-approach, something like this should work (looks a bit odd with throwing exception on success though..)

```
//numbers in ms, 10 minutes before the first run, then a new attempt every minute
@Scheduled(initialDelay= 600000, fixedDelay = 60000) 
public void doTask() {
   try {
      doTheTask();
   } catch (final Exception e) {
       //do nothing, retry in 1 minute
       return;
   }
   trow new AbortScheduledException("Task complete"); //made up exception with descriptive name..
}
```

Comment: Isn't PostConstruct going to be part of startup? i mean its going to fail after 10th attempt... what is we have something which needs time lag and not iteration ...let say the task can be executed for sure after 10 minutes of start.                                                                               Well i can try this if no other solution is there.

Comment: Postconstruct is part of the startup, this will give you up to 2 seconds to wait for the data to be ready. But if you need 10 minutes then it's probably not the way to go